# Installing Giraph-Gremlin in Tinkerpop3 getting error : No FileSystem for scheme: file

Tags: tinkerpop

I'm trying to install Giraph-Gremlin in in Tinkerpop3:

```
$ bin/gremlin.sh

       \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: server
plugin activated: utilities
gremlin> :install com.tinkerpop giraph-gremlin 3.0.0.M1
==>loaded: [com.tinkerpop, giraph-gremlin, 3.0.0.M1] - restart the console to use [giraph]
gremlin> :q
$ bin/gremlin.sh

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: server
plugin activated: utilities
gremlin> :plugin use giraph
No FileSystem for scheme: file
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That wasn't a problem with M1 that I know of.  Could you please try M2 which was just released yesterday?  I can help you debug from there if it is still an issue.

Comment: I tried M2, still got a same problem.

Comment: what version of hadoop are you using?

Comment: This has to do with Hadoop being improperly installed. I've seen this before in the past with Faunus and other Hadoop applications. I suspect your .bash_profile ENVs are not set correctly. I don't know completely though.....?

Comment: I follow the instruction from http://giraph.apache.org/quick_start.html, it deploys giraph and runs giraph job successfully. the following is my ENV setting:
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/ec2-user/hadoop-1.2.1
export GIRAPH_HOME=/home/ec2-user/giraph
export M2_HOME=/home/ec2-user/apache-maven-3.2.3
export M2=$M2_H0ME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_05
export GlRAPH_GREMLlN_LlBS=/home/ec2-user/tinkerpop3/ext/giraph-gremlin
export PATH=$M2:$JAVA_H0ME/bin:$PATH:~/node/bin

Comment: Here's all the hadoop related stuff I have set: https://gist.github.com/spmallette/accaa6cbdcb98f08b7a9

Comment: I followed the hadoop config above, I didn't get 'No FileSystem for scheme: file', but getting 'No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs' instead.

Comment: Finally, I got it to work. the setting should be:

Comment: export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:$HADOOP_PREFIX/*:$HADOOP_PREFIX/lib/*export 
GIRAPH_GREMLIN_LIBS=/home/ec2-user/tinkerpop3/gremlin-console/target/gremlin-console-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone/ext/giraph-gremlin/

Comment: why not post it as a self answer and accept it>